# How to get apple id from In-app Purchase transaction_id

Tags: ios, iphone

In my application when user will buy any product using In- app Purchase i can not force user please log in in my application [ That is apple condition]

When a user will buy any product apple just give a in app purchase **transaction_id** .

In that case i can not keep track any users information in my system.
later when the user will restore his In - app purchase product in another device, without any user track/ apple id/ Unique ID i can not manage my application.

how to i can get apple users unique id by transaction_id..?

Answer (score 8):

The in-app purchase receipt fields do not have any PII (personally identifiable information). See details in the [Receipt validation programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH106-SW12). In other words, you can not get user's apple-id from a transaction-id.

If you just want to be able to restore previous purchases, you can do so by restoring purchased products. See the details in [In-app purchase programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Restoring.html)

If you want to track the user for other purposes, you can have the user login in the app before showing them the purchase screens.

Comment: Hi Sinatra thank you for your answer. To get user's information, If the user not log in then we tell the user please log in before purchase. But apple reject our application for this condition. we must remove user log in before In app purchase.

Comment: They rejected the app because you're asking the user to login just before a purchase. If you ask the user to login at the start of the app, then you should be okay. Apple understands that some apps need the user to signup/login so that the apps can synchronize the user data across multiple devices.

Comment: In that case we can't show the user our free product or which product he will buy. because in many case user avoid application just for log in first.

Comment: @atiksarker - I have a question, I know that it's a long time but do you remember the rejection purpose? Which part of Guideline did they provide you as a reason of reject? Also was your app iOS only?

Comment: @Apan i can't remember details of rejection but the case was like let's say user want to purchase item with In-app purchase when user click on buy then in that time we can not set our login condition  [ This condition given us by apple ]. Our application was in android, ios & windows platform.

Comment: Thanks for response!

Comment: @atiksarker i am facing a similar scenario, How did you manage to get your app approved by app store?

Comment: for in app purchase the login should be optional